# For SSAS Cube lift and shift approach, does migrating to snowflake, will it be an advantage for better performance and how

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

For SSAS Cube lift and shift approach, does migrating to the snowflake, will it be an advantage for better performance and how.

Where do we store a cube in snowflake. Becaues it only accepts relational Dbs.
if we keep cube on Azure, and using snowflake, how we configure so we can use snowflake engine.

Answer (score 2):

1. There are so many different variables that the only way of knowing if Snowflake will perform better than your current solution, and if the cost of moving to Snowflake is worth it, is to try it
2. You can't store a SSAS cube in Snowflake as they are 2 different technologies. If you are going to move over to Snowflake then you'll need to drop your cube and use normal tables in Snowflake. SSAS cubes are a Microsoft solution to query performance; Snowflake has its own architectural solutions to delivering fast analytical query performance